# "Нотабене"

Tags: этимология, орфография

Что такое "нотабене" и как правильно писать: слитно или раздельно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выражение происходит от латинского "nota bene" - "хорошо заметить" и означает нечто, на что нужно обратить внимание, заметка на полях. В русском это выражение стало устойчивым и пишется слитно.